Unable to download the IntelliJ Idea plugins(shows all plugins grayed-out)
I have IntelliJ Idea License, but when i tried to search the plugin and try to download, it does not download.
It shows all plugins grayed-out with IntelliJ idea plugin(does not shows the which ever plug logo it may be).
I have tried to uninstall and reinstall multiple times added license key but still it shows the same and unable to download the plugins

Have you tried installing a plugin from the disk? Does it work? --> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#install_plugin_from_disk
